# How do you use setValue in the MS Access macro builder to insert today's date?

Tags: macros, ms-access-2010

I'm modifying the "duplicate" button from the wizard in MS Access 2010 to modify a couple of fields when a record is duplicated. I'm trying to get it to change a date field to today's date. I've tried entering `today()` as the expression, but I get an error saying:

> The object does not contain the automation object "today"

Can someone help a poor noob out and tell me how I can get todays date to populate in a specified field using the macro builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the date by using the function `Now()` as the expression, without the equals sign.